# RMAN-03009: failure of backup command due to ORA-27038 and OSD-04010:

Tags: backup, oracle-12c, windows, rman

I'm running below script in a windows server, this is same script I run across all servers

```
run {  
configure retention policy to recovery window of 7 days;
 backup current controlfile format 'F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\%d\%Y-%M-%D\FULL_controlfile_%d_%T_%t'; 
 backup spfile format 'F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\%d\%Y-%M-%D\FULL_spfile_%d_%T_%t'; 
 backup incremental level 0 format 'F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\%d\%Y-%M-%D\FULL_%d_%T_%t' database ;
sql 'alter system archive log current';  
backup archivelog all format 'F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\%d\%Y-%M-%D\FULL_ARC_%d_%T_%t' delete input;
}  
crosscheck backup; 
report obsolete; 
delete noprompt obsolete; 
delete noprompt expired backup;
list backup summary; 
exit;


But I'm getting below error:

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 04/29/2020 11:30:04
ORA-19504: failed to create file "F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\TTTSCM\2020-04-29\FULL_TTTSCM_20200429_1039001396"
ORA-27038: created file already exists
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
```

Control file and SPfile are created successfully, and directory is empty prior backup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must add unicity variable in the backup format name:
 backup incremental level 0 format 'F:\DATABASE_BACKUP\%d\%Y-%M-%D\FULL_%d_%T_%t_**%U**' database ;
As your backupset is composed of multiple backup pieces, they must have different names.